# What is the difference between あと、うしろ and のちほど?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I'm confused, because all of them seem to have the same meaning (*in my opinion). 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you share what you think they mean and perhaps provide some examples so we can help you with what you need? Please provide more details in your question. I will say though のち is much more formal than あと, but serves the same purpose.

Comment: I search them in dictionary and they have a same mean. But I dont know how do we use them in the difference case.

Comment: @macraf
how about あと and うしろ　???

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

後{あと}, 後{あと}で, and 後{のち} mean after a time. のち is more formal. 後程{のちほど} is literally "after an extent (of time)."

> 晩{ばん}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べた後{あと}で行{い}く。
>   I'll go after I eat dinner.

後{うし}ろ is physically behind.

> ゴミ箱{ばこ}は椅子{いす}の後{うし}ろにある。
>   The trash can is behind the chair.